# Mutating a dataframe in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reviewing some python code (I don't use Python often to I'm not sure what the nuances are in design patterns), and I saw the following comment

```
Mutating dataframes in a loop isn't efficient and stylistic. TODO: find alternative
```

for the following code:

```
for id in ids:
  rows4id = df.id == id
  date2scale = get_date2scale(date4id[id])
  df.loc[rows4id, "scale"] = df.loc[rows4id, "date"].map(date2scale)
```

How else can one write such code to make it "more efficient and stylistic?"

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
  "id": [0, 1, 2],
  "date": [10, 10, 10],
  "scale": [0, 0, 0]
})

ids = [1, 2]
def get_date2scale(id):
  if id == 1:
    return {10: 5.1}
  elif id == 2:
    return {10: 5.2}
  else:
    raise ValueError, "Should not be called for this id"
```

Result should be:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
  "id": [0, 1, 2],
  "date": [10, 10, 10],
  "scale": [0, 5.1, 5.2]
})
```

Comment: welcome to SO, read following notice : [mre]

Comment: How this code behaves depends on the dataset. For instance are there all IDs in `date4id`?

Comment: @mozway No they are not. Also note that `ids` may only be a subset of `df.id.unique()`

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] of the dataset (and of `get_date2scale` and `date4id`) as requested above? I believe my answer below should work but it's always better to be able to test and double check.

Comment: @mozway Yes, I just put it in. Sorry I did not include before.

Answer (score 0):

This code is essentially doing:

```
for id in ids:  # for each id
  # get a mask of the matching rows
  rows4id = df.id == id 
  # get a mapper for this id
  date2scale = get_date2scale(date4id[id])
  # replace all matching rows by the mapped value
  df.loc[rows4id, "scale"] = df.loc[rows4id, "date"].map(date2scale)
```

Which could be replaced by a [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html) after a filter with [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
m = df['id'].isin(ids)

df.loc[m, 'scale'] = (df[m].groupby('id', group_keys=False)['date']
                           .apply(lambda g: g.map(get_date2scale(g.name)))
                     )
```

This shouldn't be much more efficient though since it's essentially doing the same loops, except if `ids` contain ids that are not present in the dataframe (in this case it should be faster).

Comment: Does this assume that `ids == df.id.unique()` ?

Comment: It does not need to assume that, but is fine with it (i.e., if `ids` contained other ids then the loop would perform useless cycles and not this code, but if equal then this is essentially the same).

Comment: I do not believe `ids` will contain `id` that is not in `df.id.unique()` but it is possible that `len(ids) < df.id.unique()`, and I would not want to call `get_date2scale` for the id in `ids` that are not in `df.id.unique()`

Comment: @u2j4 indeed, this can make a difference if the function trigger an error, in this case you have to pre-filter (see update).

Answer (score 0):

use `mask`

```
idx = [1, 2]
cond = df['id'].isin(idx) & df['date'].eq(10)
df['scale'] = df['scale'].mask(cond, df['id'].mul(0.1).add(5))
```

df

```
    id  date    scale
0   0   10      0.0
1   1   10      5.1
2   2   10      5.2
```

don need make func and loop

---

if arbitrary and the function might just be a dummy example, use `np.select`

```
import numpy as np
cond1 = df['id'].eq(1)
cond2 = df['id'].eq(2)
df['scale'] = np.select([cond1, cond2], [df['date'].replace({10:5.1}), df['date'].replace({10:5.2})], df['scale'])
```

same result

Comment: I think the values are arbitrary and the function might just be a dummy example ;)